# Why I have both javascript code in .aspx file and c# codes in .cs file?

Tags: asp.net

I'm currently working on an ASP.Net web application. Just curious when I noticed that I have both javascript codes and C# codes. Is it possible to transfer all my javascript codes to c# codes to make it looks more consistent? Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that JavaScript and C# are two different things, the former being primarily client-side and the latter being server-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. JavaScript code executes on the Client Side. C# executes on the Server Side. They perform two different functions and can't be treated interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

C# is your server-side, back-end logic to support your web page. The JavaScript is client-side code running in the browser, often to improve the user experience and perform some logic or UI operations wihtout having to go to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a language that executes on the Browser, on the Client Side; C# code is executed on the web server.